# not found error when insert #!/bin/sh

Tags: shell, terminal

I started learning Linux shell scripting, when I was writing this script I got an error,

```
./my_script: 4: read: Illegal option -n
./my_script: 5: ./my_script: [[: not found
```

I found out its because  **#!/bin/sh** line, i can still run the script without that line but it won't execute codes such as **/n**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Shell installer for gurb customizer. by Naveen Gamage.

OS=$(lsb_release -si)
ARCH=$(uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/')
VER=$(lsb_release -sr)

grabninstall() {
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install grub-customizer    
}

echo "Installer for GRUB CUSTOMIZER\n"
echo "GURB CUSTOMIZER"
echo "A tool for editing and configuring boot menu (GRUB2/BURG).\n"

read -p "Do you want to install Grub Customizer for $OS ${VER} [$ARCH] ? (Y/n) " -n 1

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    echo "The installer is downloading and installing GRUB Customizer!";
    echo "This action may require your password.\n";
    grabninstall
else
    echo "user quit"
    echo "Installation was unsuccessful."
fi
```

I'm doing this on Ubuntu 12.10.

and **which sh** gives this output

```
/bin/sh
```

any idea where i did wrong?

Comment: Does `ls -l /bin/sh` point to `bash`?

Comment: yes, lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 13 16:01 /bin/sh -> dash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `/bin/sh` to run the script and on your system `/bin/sh -> dash`. This means that `dash` is executing your script. The `dash` shell does not support `[[`, but `bash` does. So you should change the first line in your script (called the [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Alternatively, don't use `[[` in your script. Only use features support by `dash`.

Also see [this Ubuntu page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on what constructs are not supported in `dash`.

Comment: why bash doesn't support **\n** command? the command for an empty line.

Comment: Is there any other way to do an empty line? except `echo ""`

Comment: Use `echo -e` to print an empty line. e.g. `echo -e "hello\nworld"`

Comment: Use just `echo` to print an empty line (no arguments). Don't use `echo` with arguments (e.g. `echo -n`/`echo -e`) if portability is a concern, use `printf` instead ([link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/echo.html#tag_04_41_16)).